# javascript not work in xhtml page ( primefaces )

Tags: javascript, xhtml

I have a text area that contains a numbers of "$VAR", i want to count the occurrence of these numbers, the javascript match function returns always null, but it works in the console ! I don't understand why ?

when i test this function match return null

```
    var regex = new RegExp("\\$VAR", "g");
    var v = $("#form\\:idtextarea").val();
    var count = v.match(regex).length ;
    alert(count);
```

but when i run this command under the console browser it returns the correct result !

```
    $("#form\\:idtextarea").val().match(new RegExp("\\$VAR", "g")).length
```

this code is included in a XHTML page

Comment: Probably `v` doesn't contain what you think it does. Perhaps you're running the code before the DOM elements involved have been loaded.

Comment: Since you mention the browser console... Are you aware of `console.log()` and other utility methods?

Comment: thanks for answer, no i am running this code by a button always after filling the textarea with a lot of $VAR

Comment: It would still be worthwhile to add an alert() or console.log() to your code to see what `v` contains.

Comment: use console.log() to check your variables, it's either "v" or "regex" that returns null

Comment: thanks for answers, no! alert or console.log() is not important i just used them to check what count contains v.match is always null and i am wondering why ?

Comment: Good to hear diagnose tools are not important. Then we'll keep on trying blind shots until we guess the correct answer.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález please don't understand me wrong(due to my bad English) :/ when i says that alert or console.log() are not important is referring to this code already posted in fact i have used them to test my code before posting the question after that i have used the browser console just to check if my instruction is correct then i found that the instruction works correctly in the browser console. sorry again

Comment: What is the type of the button.

Comment: thank you @MrLister. i am using primefaces and i tried p:commandButton , p:button and even h:button always the same problem i will test my code on a simple html page and see what will happen

Comment: @HichemABDELLALI I want to know what the `type` attribute of the generated button says. Is it `button` or `submit`?

Comment: @MrLister the generated type of p:commandButton is a submit button and p:button is a button i tried both of them

Comment: this code work correctly in a simple html page

Comment: thank you I found the solution thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved when I have used the default component `<h:outputScript name="file.js" />`
 to include javascript after an `<ui:define>` instead of including it directly like an html page